# PHP MYSQL Insert into with switch statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, switch-statement, sql-insert

first of all, I'm sorry because I'm still a newbie and want to learn more about coding.

I'm currently working on this.
My 1st, 2nd, and 3rd table are working fine. My problem is my 4th table is not receiving any values.
I trying to insert data on my 4th table with a switch statement where $eGrad is equal to Grade Level.
I want to insert values on my st_grade table(4th table) base on grade level and some of them are constant values.

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks!
Here is the code that I'm working

```
public function insert($stID, $eFullname, $eGrad, $secID, $eStatus, $eSY, $syID,  $rformOne, $rformTwo, $rPsa, $rGm, $rPic){

        $firstTB = "INSERT INTO st_enrolled (e_stid, e_fullname,e_grade,e_status,e_sy) VALUES('$stID', '$eFullname', '$eGrad',  '$eStatus', '$eSY')";
        $secondTB = "INSERT INTO st_sy (st_sy_stid, st_sy_syid) VALUES('$stID', '$syID')";
        $thirdTB = "INSERT INTO st_requirement (str_id, str_fullname, formOne, formTwo, psa, goodmoral, picture) VALUES ('$stID', '$eFullname',  '$rformOne', '$rformTwo', '$rPsa', '$rGm', '$rPic')";
        
        
        switch($eGrad){
            
            case "Grade1" :
                $fourthTB = "INSERT INTO `st_grade`(`st_id`,`subj_id`,`gr_id`,`sec_id`,`sy_id`,`first`,`second`,`third`,`fourth`,`ave`,`remarks`) VALUES 
                ($stID, 1, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 2, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 3, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 4, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 5, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 6, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 7, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),";
                break;
            case "Grade2" :
                $fourthTB = "INSERT INTO `st_grade`(`st_id`,`subj_id`,`gr_id`,`sec_id`,`sy_id`,`first`,`second`,`third`,`fourth`,`ave`,`remarks`) VALUES 
                ($stID, 8, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 9, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 10, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 11, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 12, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 13, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 14, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),";
                break;  
            default: 
                echo "error";
        }


        if ($this->conn->query($firstTB) && $this->conn->query($secondTB) && $this->conn->query($thirdTB) && $this->conn->query($fourthTB) ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? and what exactly is your question?  Check how to [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've deleted last comma in your sql string now it should works

```
public function insert($stID, $eFullname, $eGrad, $secID, $eStatus, $eSY, $syID,  $rformOne, $rformTwo, $rPsa, $rGm, $rPic){

        $firstTB = "INSERT INTO st_enrolled (e_stid, e_fullname,e_grade,e_status,e_sy) VALUES('$stID', '$eFullname', '$eGrad',  '$eStatus', '$eSY')";
        $secondTB = "INSERT INTO st_sy (st_sy_stid, st_sy_syid) VALUES('$stID', '$syID')";
        $thirdTB = "INSERT INTO st_requirement (str_id, str_fullname, formOne, formTwo, psa, goodmoral, picture) VALUES ('$stID', '$eFullname',  '$rformOne', '$rformTwo', '$rPsa', '$rGm', '$rPic')";
        
        
        switch($eGrad){
            
            case "Grade1" :
                $fourthTB = "INSERT INTO `st_grade`(`st_id`,`subj_id`,`gr_id`,`sec_id`,`sy_id`,`first`,`second`,`third`,`fourth`,`ave`,`remarks`) VALUES 
                ($stID, 1, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 2, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 3, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 4, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 5, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 6, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 7, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '')";
                break;
            case "Grade2" :
                $fourthTB = "INSERT INTO `st_grade`(`st_id`,`subj_id`,`gr_id`,`sec_id`,`sy_id`,`first`,`second`,`third`,`fourth`,`ave`,`remarks`) VALUES 
                ($stID, 8, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 9, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 10, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 11, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 12, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 13, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
                ($stID, 14, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '')";
                break;  
            default: 
                echo "error";
        }


        if ($this->conn->query($firstTB) && $this->conn->query($secondTB) && $this->conn->query($thirdTB) && $this->conn->query($fourthTB) ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Typo questions should not be answered, they should insted be flagged as such (`Flag` link under the question > 'needs improvement' > 'a community specific reason' > 'not reproducible or caused by a typo'), alongside leaving a comment instructing the OP on the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

comma at the end is causing problem

before

```
($stID, 7, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),";
($stID, 14, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),";
```

after

```
($stID, 7, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '')";
($stID, 14, $eGrad, $secID, $syID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '')";
```

remove comma(,) at the end in both switch cases and it'll work fine

Comment: Typo questions should not be answered, they should insted be flagged as such (`Flag` link under the question > 'needs improvement' > 'a community specific reason' > 'not reproducible or caused by a typo'), alongside leaving a comment instructing the OP on the cause of the issue.